# Eclipse - Export Signed Application Package Not Producing APK

Tags: java, android, eclipse

For some reason, when I try to export a signed application package using ADT tools, some kind of unspecified file type is produced instead of an APK. This only started just recently - before then, I had never had a problem like this. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Eclipse has such kinda a issues just uninstall or delete its folder and download then use a new copy of eclipse setting up your desired workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does eclipse also exit when you have this problem?

I recently got issues with exporting signed packages myself but in my case eclipse would fail and shut down. Also there was no output at all (on os x). The problem seems to occur when working with several projects being signed that refer to a common library.

For me the solution is to do a clean build before exporting the signed package. A clean build of project and libraries.

Comment: No, it doesn't shut down. I've also tried clean building beforehand. It's particularly odd because I've never had this issue with this project before.